# What is the best framework to make 2d games on iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, physics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [physics library for iphone programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847846/physics-library-for-iphone-programming)

I want to start making physics based 2d games like tiny wings or iStunt.

I know cocos2d is an option, but is that the best option for these types of games.

Comment: possible duplicate of [physics library for iphone programming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847846/physics-library-for-iphone-programming) or [iPhone 2D game dev](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694993/conceptual-iphone-2d-game-dev-question-quartz-cocos2d-chipmunk-box2d)

Comment: i'm not looking for a physics library, I just want to know what tiny wings or angry birds use to code their games

Comment: best = easiest or most features

Comment: @GeeGoldz - Which one? "Easiest" and "Most features" is more or less a contradiction in terms. You can't have both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Cocos2d.](http://cocos2d-iphone.org)

The documentation for **cocos2d-iphone** is very well documented and described then others.and used by most of very famous iPhone/iPad games,

they have full working example of games, which you could download and test.

But still you could have look into others.

[Open Source 2D iPhone and iPad Game Framework](http://maniacdev.com/2010/06/open-source-2d-iphone-and-ipad-game-framework/)